# Word 2013: New File from template disables macros

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a template with a macro that runs every time I open the .dotm file.
However when I go to New and click on the template it generates the new file based on the template and with references to its code but the macro doesn't run.

What I need for the macro to do is to open a form in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this article (old but still relevant) which should help:

- [Running a macro automatically when a document is created, opened or closed](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/documentevents.htm).

Basically, you need to handle the `AutoNew()` and possibly the `AutoOpen()` events in your code module.